# Cambiar ruta de python en include dependiendo de si se está en Linux o en Windows

Tags: c++, qt

Después de desarrollar mi aplicación en Qt en mi ordenador (linux) me está costando horrores poderlo compilar fuera de él. 
Algunas cosas las he resuelto, pero ahora me da problemas ya que hago uso de Python. Entonces, en el fichero correspondiente tengo esto:

```
#include "/usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h"
```

(Que de hecho pienso que ya sólo en linux le podría ocasionar problemas a alguien que quiera compilarlo y no tenga exactamente python en esa ruta)

Pero en este caso se trata de que la ruta de Python en Windows en diferente, y me da el lógico y correspondiente error.

Así que la pregunta es...podría definir esta ruta de forma que me busque los archivos en un sitio u otro según esté dentro de windows o linux.

Y ya por hacer la pregunta más extensa....y ¿en general habría alguna forma de que busque la ruta de Python y establezca el `#include` adecuado?

**Edito:**

Siguiendo la respuesta de @eyllanesc, muestro mi modificación en el archivo pro, por si a alguien le aclara más las ideas:

```
unix{
    LIBS += -L /usr/local/lib/python3.6 -lpython3.6m
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/python3.6m
}
win32{    
    LIBS += -L C:\Python\Python37\libs -lpython37
    INCLUDEPATH += C:/Python/Python37/include
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En general no es una buena practica colocar un include usando la ruta absoluta de una librería externa.

Asi que asumiendo que estas usando qmake para tu proyecto entonces puedes acortar la ruta usando INCLUDEPATH:

***.pro**

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/python3.6m
```

y solo usar `#include <Python.h>` para incluir la libreria.

---

Entonces considerando lo anterior solo es necesario cambiar el INCLUDEPATH segun la OS, y qmake lo permite facilmente:

```
unix{
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/python3.6m
}
win32{
    INCLUDEPATH += la_otra_ruta
}
```